# WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/CustomerDetails/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'customerdispatcher'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
I had a issue in spring3 frameowrk.org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/CustomerDetails/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'customerdispatcher'




Please see the following
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Sony\VAIO Improvement\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sony\VAIO Startup Setting Tool;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin;;.
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:28 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:CustomerDetails' did not find a matching property.
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1635 ms
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.50
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:30 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\Smileanbu\Documents\Spring_JDBC\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\CustomerDetails\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'customerdispatcher'
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:33 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'customerdispatcher': initialization started
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:33 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'customerdispatcher-servlet': startup date [Sun Jun 01 11:16:33 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:34 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/customerdispatcher-servlet.xml]
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:34 AM org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider registerDefaultFilters
INFO: JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:35 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@19705d39: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,viewResolver,dataSource,sessionFactory,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionManager,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
300 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final
312 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.6.10.Final
315 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
321 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
327 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
479 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from url: file:/C:/Users/Smileanbu/Documents/Spring_JDBC/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/CustomerDetails/WEB-INF/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml
538 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
594 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configured SessionFactory: null
688 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.springforbeginners.model.Customer
778 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.springforbeginners.model.Customer on table CUSTOMER
900 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:36 AM org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean buildSessionFactory
INFO: Building new Hibernate SessionFactory
919 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.search.HibernateSearchEventListenerRegister - Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.
929 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory - Initializing connection provider: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider
1606 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
1641 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Database ->
       name : MySQL
    version : 5.1.73-community
      major : 5
      minor : 1
1641 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Driver ->
       name : MySQL-AB JDBC Driver
    version : mysql-connector-java-5.1.14 ( Revision: ${bzr.revision-id} )
      major : 5
      minor : 1
1644 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory - Transaction strategy: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringTransactionFactory
1648 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory - No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
1648 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
1648 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
1649 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC batch size: 15
1649 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled
1651 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Scrollable result sets: enabled
1651 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled
1651 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Connection release mode: auto
1653 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Maximum outer join fetch depth: 2
1654 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Default batch fetch size: 1
1654 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Generate SQL with comments: disabled
1654 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
1654 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
1654 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
1661 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
1661 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query language substitutions: {}
1661 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
1663 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Second-level cache: enabled
1663 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query cache: disabled
1663 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.NoCachingRegionFactory
1681 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
1681 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
1699 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Echoing all SQL to stdout
1701 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Statistics: disabled
1702 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
1702 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Default entity-mode: pojo
1702 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Named query checking : enabled
1702 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Check Nullability in Core (should be disabled when Bean Validation is on): enabled
1751 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - building session factory
1788 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [characters_clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.PrimitiveCharacterArrayClobType@236f7565
1788 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.ClobType@6a844c0f
1788 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [java.sql.Clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.ClobType@6a844c0f
1788 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [wrapper_characters_clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.CharacterArrayClobType@139da36b
1788 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [materialized_clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.MaterializedClobType@5253cfdc
1788 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [materialized_blob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.MaterializedBlobType@7c739ebd
1788 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [wrapper_materialized_blob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.WrappedMaterializedBlobType@abaca20
1789 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [blob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.BlobType@6d2c0060
1789 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [java.sql.Blob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.BlobType@6d2c0060
2313 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:38 AM org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@1c53ccd6] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:38 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'customerdispatcher': initialization completed in 4758 ms
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 10104 ms
Jun 01, 2014 11:16:40 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/CustomerDetails/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'customerdispatcher'
```

customerdispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springforbeginners.controller.CustomerController" />
  <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customerdb"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="123456"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>customerdispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>customerdispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
</web-app>
```

CustomerController class

```
package com.springforbeginners.controller;

import com.springforbeginners.model.Customer;
import com.springforbeginners.service.CustomerService;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class CustomerController {
  @Autowired
  private CustomerService customerService;

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String listCustomers(Map<String, Object> map) {
        map.put("customer", new Customer());
        map.put("customerList", customerService.listCustomer());
        return "customer";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addCustomer(@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer, BindingResult result) {
        customerService.addCustomer(customer);
        return "redirect:/index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/delete/{customerId}")
    public String deleteCustomer(@PathVariable("customerId") Integer customerId) {
        customerService.removeCustomer(customerId);
        return "redirect:/index";
    }
}
```

I am not  able to get my customer.jsp page it is present in my WEB_INF/jsp/customer.jsp.Please help me from this error No matching Http request for URL
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/CustomerDetails/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'customerdispatcher'

Comment: In what you posted, I don't see any controller method mapped to `/CustomerDetails/`. All I see is a mapping to /index, /add and /delete/{customerId}. Why do you think Spring should handle a request with the path `/CustomerDetails/`?

Answer (score -1):

In your controller or your `web.xml`, there's nothing that maps yor URI to CustomerDetails. You should either change

`<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`  to  `<url-pattern>/CustomerDetails</url-pattern>`

or add this in your controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "CustomerDetails")
public class CustomerController {
...
}
```

And then you can call the url by:

```
Context/CustomerDetails/index
```

And by the way, in your `<welcome-file-list>`, if you are trying to call the servlet on initializing, it won't work, the `<welcome-file>` has to be a "file".